# NullReferenceException on outer join

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to grab all data from FDerive, however I am try to set a filter with a where clause.  Unfortunately I am getting a nullreferencexpection when I touch spd when a row in spd is null.

```
var Result = from fpd in FDerive
                             join spd in SDerive
                             on new { fpd.PId, fpd.SId }
                             equals new { spd.PId, spd.SId } into allRows
                             from spd in allRows.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where spd.SId == ""
                             || spd.PId == ""
                             select new { fpd, spd };
```

How do I get around the null error?

Comment: do you need right-join here or inner join?

Comment: Also. You are checking if they are empty, shouldn't you be checking if they are not empty?

Comment: I guess that is my problem, everything I've tried to check for empty trips the null error.  Still looking for the right combo to check for null

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultIfEmpty<T>` will return a set containing only one element with the default value of `T` - in this case `null` - if the source collection is empty. So `spd` will be `null` if there are no items returned in the join.

Try to a `null` check in the where clause

```
var Result = 
    ...
    where spd == null || spd.SId == "" || spd.PId == ""
    select new { fpd, spd };
```

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974088/linq-double-left-join

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at the bottom of the code in the following question

[LINQ double left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974088/linq-double-left-join)

```
var results =
        from person in students
        join entry in subquery on person.FullName equals entry.AuthorFullName into personEntries
        from personEntry in personEntries.DefaultIfEmpty()
        orderby person.FullName
        select new
        {
            PersonName = person.FullName,
            BlogTitle = personEntry == null ? "" : personEntry.Title
        };
```